# Error Custom Validation Rule Laravel Test

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Me encuentro haciendo un test unitario con Laravel8 para el metodo store de Articulos, que valida que el titulo tenga la primera letra con mayuscula. Para ello estoy utilizando un **Custom validation rule**

*Acá está lo que tengo en código:*

Uppercase.php

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return strtoupper($value) === $value;
    }

public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute does not start with an uppercased letter';
    }
```

ArticleController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => ['required', 'string', new Uppercase]
        ]);

        Article::create(['title' => $request->title]);
    }
```

El test ValidationTest

```
public function test_custom_validation_rule()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $response = $this->post('articles', ['title' => 'lowercase']);
        $response->assertSessionHasErrors([
            'title' => 'The title does not start with an uppercased letter',
        ])->assertStatus(302);

        $response = $this->post('articles', ['title' => 'Uppercase']);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

*De momento me está arrojando este error al momento de ejecutarlo:*

```
FAIL  Tests\Feature\ValidationTest
  ⨯ custom validation rule

  ---

  • Tests\Feature\ValidationTest > custom validation rule
   Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException 

  The given data was invalid.
```

si quito el withoutExceptionsHandling, me muestra el siguiente

```
mensaje:
 • Tests\Feature\ValidationTest > custom validation rule
  Expected response status code [200] but received 302.

  The following errors occurred during the request:

  The title does not start with an uppercased letter

  Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 302.

  at C:\laragon\www\Test-Laravel-Validation\tests\Feature\ValidationTest.php:118
    114▕             'title' => 'The title does not start with an uppercased letter',
    115▕         ])->assertStatus(302);
    116▕
    117▕         $response = $this->post('articles', ['title' => 'Uppercase']);
  ➜ 118▕         $response->assertStatus(200);
    119▕     }
    120▕ }
    121▕

  1   C:\laragon\www\Test-Laravel-Validation\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit:92
      PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()


  Tests:  1 failed, 8 passed
  Time:   14.93s
```

Espero me puedan dar alguna pista de como solucionarlo
Gracias

Comment: Que pasa si quitas `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();`?

Comment: Hola @porloscerrosΨ. actualicé la pregunta. gracias por comentar.

Comment: Si `$value` es `Uppercase`, entonces esto: `strtoupper($value) === $value;` siempre devolverá `false`. Ya que `strtoupper` convierte todos los caracteres de `Uppercase` en mayúsculas, por lo tanto al comparar `UPPERCASE` con `Uppercase` va a fallar. Puedes comprobarlo enviando `UPPERCASE` directamente y verás que la validación pasa. Pero eso no es lo que necesitas, sino que sólo la primera letra sea mayúscula, por lo tanto debes reescribir tu función. Saludos

Comment: Pista: utiliza [`ucfirst()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ucfirst.php) para la comparación en vez de `strtoupper`. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la explicación @MauricioContreras

---
```
 ✓ custom validation rule

  Tests:  passed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Actualmente tu función de validación realiza el siguiente proceso:

```php
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return strtoupper($value) === $value;
}
```

Si $value tiene el siguiente valor: `Uppercase`, entonces esto:

```php
strtoupper($value) === $value;
```

siempre devolverá false. Ya que [`strtoupper()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtoupper.php) convierte **todos** los caracteres de `Uppercase` en mayúsculas, por lo tanto al comparar `UPPERCASE` con `Uppercase` va a fallar.

Puedes comprobarlo enviando `UPPERCASE` directamente y verás que la validación pasa.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Tomando en cuenta lo que necesitas: que sólo la primera letra sea mayúscula, debes reescribir tu función.

En este caso, puedes apoyarte del método [`ucfirst()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ucfirst.php), que convierte el promer carácter de una cadena en mayúscula.

Tu función de validación podría verse así:

```php
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return ucfirst($value) === $value;
}
```

Ahora, al comparar `Uppercase` con `Uppercase`, la validación será superada, sin embargo toma en cuenta lo siguiente, dado que `ucfirst()` convierte sólo el primer carácter en mayúscula, entonces validar `UPPERCASE` con `UPPERCASE` también será válido e incluso validar `UppERcase` con `UppERcase`.

Si deseas que sólo el primer carácter se encuentre en mayúsculas y el resto en minúsculas, debes convertir primero todo a minúsculas (ver [`strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtolower.php)) y luego aplicar mayúsculas al primer carácter. Sólo después de hacer estas conversiones podrás comparar contra el valor recibido.

Por ejemplo:

```php
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return ucfirst(strtolower($value)) === $value;
}
```

De esta forma esto: `UpperCase` o `UPPERCASE` no serán válidos, siendo válido únicamente `Uppercase`. Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio